# Department head has requested I lower student grades

Tags: teaching, grades, grading

I’ve been teaching a 4th year business elective for the past 8-years. Grades for my class generally range from about 57% - 94%, with the average at 86%. This current teaching year, the chair of my department called me up to say that my class average is too high and that I need to lower it to 79% max. The department head also indicated that class averages were public and students could see them before enrolling in a class, and insinuated that students were enrolling more in my class than others because of the high average.

I truly believe that the bulk of my students do an amazing job and that they earn the grade they deserve. I have failed students in the past (students who consistently skipped classes, didn’t deliver assignments, or never participated); but generally, participation, attendance, and assignments are all quite strong in my class. I’ve spoken to a few of my teaching assistants, and without hesitation, they have all told me that my class has the fewest skips they’ve ever seen in any of their 4th year classes and the highest overall engagement. In my mind, it makes sense that students would receive a higher grade in my class versus another class where they’re consistently skipping more and engaging less.

I don’t want to be argumentative, but I also don’t want to penalize students in my class unfairly. I’m very inclined to simply share my opinion with the dean and acquiesce to the request. I’m curious if other teachers have faced a similar situation and what they did. I’m also curious to know any student opinions on situations they may have seen in their classes. Thanks!